# почему если input не в фокусе, кнопка не пропадает?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если input в фокусе, то кнопка должна появиться. Если фокус с input пропал, то кнопка должна пропасть. Не могу понять, почему не работает

```js
$input = $('.search__input');
$submit = $('.search__button');
$submit_active = 'search__button_active';

$input.on('click', function() {
  if ($input.is(':focus')) {
    $submit.addClass($submit_active);
  } else {
    $submit.removeClass($submit_active);
  }
});
```

```css
.search__button {
  display: none;
}

.search__button_active {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="search__input">
  <button class="search__button" type="submit">Найти</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать события [focus/blur](https://learn.javascript.ru/focus-blur#sobytiya-focus-blur)

```js
$input = $('.search__input');
$submit = $('.search__button');
$submit_active = 'search__button_active';

$input.on('focus blur', function() {
  $submit.toggleClass($submit_active);
});
```

```css
.search__button {
  display: none;
}

.search__button_active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="search__input">
  <button class="search__button" type="submit">Найти</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз вам нужен jquery - используйте то, что jquery вам дает нахаляву -

https://api.jquery.com/focusin/

https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

и используйте специализированные функции

```js
$input = $('.search__input');
$submit = $('.search__button');
$submit_active = 'search__button_active';

$input.focusin(function() {
    $submit.addClass($submit_active);
});

$input.focusout(function() {
    $submit.removeClass($submit_active);
});
```

```css
.search__button {
  display: none;
}

.search__button_active {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="search__input">
  <button class="search__button" type="submit">Найти</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам JQuery?

Тут чистый css

```css
.search__input + .search__button {
    display: none;
}
  
.search__input:focus + .search__button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="search__input">
  <button class="search__button" type="submit">Найти</button>
</div>
```

Comment: потому что изначальный код сложнее, а тут я его упростил

Comment: ну тогда ответ на ваш вопрос  - потому что вы отлавливаете `$input.on('click', function() {`, а снятие фокуса, т.е. клик в другое место или нажатие табуляции и т.д. с этим событием вообще никак не связано. И кстати вместо `add` и `remove` лучше использовать `toggle`